# How do you write your class's data to wostringstream in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, ostream, wostringstream

Say I have a class B which includes an array of class A, I want to use **std::wostringstream** to output the data in class B. I have overloaded the operator `<<` for Class B, but I just get 'E0349' and 'C2679' error.

Definition of class A

```
class A
{
public:
    A();
    ~A();
    inline A(float _x, float _y, float _z) :
        x(_x), y(_y), z(_z)
    {
    }
    inline void Set(float _x, float _y, float _z);

    float x, y, z;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const A& source);
    friend std::wostringstream& operator<<(std::wostringstream& out, const A& source);
private:

};
```

Definition of class B

```
class B
{
public:
    A* ArrayOfA;
    bool Initialize(const A* samples,
        unsigned int count);
    friend std::wostringstream& operator<<(std::wostringstream& out, const B& source);

    B();
    ~B();

private:

};
```

As you can see,class B have an array of class A.
I have overloaded the operator `<<` for class A.

```
std::wostringstream&
operator<<(std::wostringstream& out, const A& source)
{
    out << '<' << source.x << ',' << source.y << ',' << source.z << '>';

    return out;
}
```

Now, I want to use Class B like:

```
std::wostringstream wss;
wss << ClassB
```

But I can not.

Here is the error code, I have overloaded operator `<<` for Class B

```
std::wostringstream&
operator<<(std::wostringstream& out, const B& source)
{

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        out << ":" << source.ArrayOfA[i] << std::endl;
        // ERROR:E0349 no operator "<<" matches these operands
        // ERROR:C2679 binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type'A' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
    }

    return out;

}
```

Here is the full code. It's online compiler.

[A little bit of long code sample, but with details](https://onlinegdb.com/SyIS4hEyD)

The full code is in the URL.

What is wrong? How would you send the *ArrayOfA* to **std::wostringstream**? If you just only use std::ostream, how would you get the string content like std::wostringstream? Is there anything wrong with my operator overloading?

Comment: Please post your code as part of the question in text, in a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Likely `A` doesn't have a `<<` overload, but it's impossible to be sure with what's been given. Could we hit you up for a [mre]? Odds are good that making the MRE will lead you to the solution without any further help.

Comment: The goal of Stack Overflow is to build a repository of questions and answers that future programmers can use. Links rot, making that impossible. Why we ask for [mre]: It is a distillation of powerful debugging techniques. It's hard to make a good MRE and not find the solution to your problem. If you are asking for help debugging and you haven't already isolated the problem with a MRE or something like it, you've been wasting your time.

Comment: I have added more details.Thanks for all of the suggestions.

Comment: I have added more details.Thanks for all of the suggestions.

Comment: This is close enough for me, but a proper MRE is a small program that can (in the case of a compiler error) be dropped into a text file and compiled to produce the error you're asking about. You have all the right pieces here and just need to organize them better to have a MRE. Once you have an MRE, you can use it to experiment and to prove that any fixes you attempt solve the problem (and preferably don't introduce new ones). It's much easier to test small amounts of code than big, so you can validate the fix much faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that `std::wostringstream << char` (or `wchar_t`) returns a `std::wostream` and **not** a `std::wostringstream`. So, effectively,

```
out << '<' << source.ArrayOfA[i];
```

Would be looking for the function

```
std::wostream &operator<<( std::wostream &out, const A & );
```

What you really want, is to take in, and return an `std::wostream`.

```
std::wostream&
operator<<(std::wostream& out, const A& source)
{
    out << '<' << source.x << ',' << source.y << ',' << source.z << '>';
    return out;
}

std::wostream&
operator<<(std::wostream& out, const B& source)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        out << L":" << source.ArrayOfA[i] << std::endl; 
    }
    return out;
}
```

`std::wostream` is compatible with `std::wostringstream`, so something like this will still work:

```
std::wostringstream wss;
wss << ClassB
```